# Bracket for specify multiple files under a directory not works in Makefile

Tags: makefile, brackets

I tried this
`g++ hello_world.cc -Iinclude /some/path/{file1,file2}.a` on terminal and it worked well.
However, I put this line into a **Makefile**, it said **file /some/path/{file1,file2}.a not found**. It seems that the brackets not work in Makefile.

Comment: I want to include both **file1** and **file2** under **/some/path/**, which I can specify with **/some/path/{file1,file2}** under the shell. However, the bracket semantic seems not work in a Makefile. It treats it as **"/some/path/{file1,file2}"** (note the quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your question is, but try adding the line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: I already has `#!/bin/sh`. But it does not solve the problem.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is not `#!/bin/bash`, and `/bin/sh` is precisely the problem.  `/bin/sh` does not recognize the shell syntax you are trying to use.